# How to get Git Stats from VSTS

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

We use VSTS and are looking for some stats around amount and size of git commits, by author.  How can I obtain this from our VSTS Git repositories?

The only one I've found so far is Git Stats, which involves pulling all repo's locally etc, so doesn't sound as sustainable.

Given that VSTS seems to expose some of this info, on project Activity pane, I was hopeful it'd be available somehow/somewhere.

[image: VSTS Activity info pane]

One of the drivers behind this is to identify those who store up really large commits.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn’t the built-in feature of Git stats for VSTS Git repository.

You can build an extension (e.g. dashboard widget) with your own logical per to detail requirement to analysis the data from Git Rest API.

There is the article about step by step to create a dashboard widget: [Add a dashboard widget](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-dashboard-widget).

To get related data of commits, you can use this API in your extension: [GitHttpClient2_2](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/versioncontrol/gitrestclient/githttpclient2_2)

Answer (score 2):

I wanted the same thing as well, so after the search I'm happy with what PowerBI gives me:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/powerbi/report-on-vso-with-power-bi-vs

It gives the commits by author and much more that I didn't expect as pull requests info.
It's simple to setup: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/powerbi/connect-vso-pbi-vs

Cheers,

Comment: Power BI is now deprecated until improvements are made. ["We are deprecating the Power BI.com Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) Content Pack on November 15, 2017 primarily due to the negative impact it has had on VSTS accounts, including throttling end users access."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/powerbi/connect-vso-pbi-vs)

Comment: Seems that PowerBI is back in business https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=azure-devops